# How to get properties of a video file?

Tags: php, video

I have a video path, how i can get the properties of this file in PHP ?
Ex: width, height, dimension...

Have a easy method like a getimagesize() ?
I will use the mp4/avi formats... and im using the video.js plugin

Comment: your question is tagged with `php` but you are using a `js` plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough rep. to add a comment(Sorry).

Did you try this?
[getID3()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)