# Video upload check "Only 30 second video will upload"

Tags: php, video

I am working with PHP. I want to find a way to upload a maximum of 30 second video clips on upload. How to check that the uploaded video duration is only 30 seconds long?

Also, I want to find a way with PHP to convert a video in other formats such as MP4.

Please suggest us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ID3 information of the file and probably do a check later:

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);

// Access duration and dimensions 
$duration = $file['playtime_string']; 
$dimensions = $file['filesize'];
```

If you want to convert it in other formats there is this package [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

Also check these resources:

- http://getid3.sourceforge.net/
- http://ffmpeg.org/
- Similar question: [How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)