# Php ffmpeg get video duration

Tags: php, shell, video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

How can I get a video duration and print it out as an php output,

like echo $duration.

So far I used this command:

> ffprobe -i C:\FFMpeg\bunny.mp4 -show_format | findstr duration

to looks for the video duration.

I got some output plus this:

```
...
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
duration=60.095000
```

I do not know how to get that duration and print in down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I did it finally, but I do not know if it is the best practice, but for me it is ok at the moment, what I did is saving the duration in a temporary text file.

Command:

> cd C:\FFMpeg\bin; .\ffprobe -i " . $path . " -show_format | findstr
>   duration >
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bass\storage\generator\projects\duration.txt

Now I will access that file with php and get the content of it.

Answer (score 0):

Should use 'ffmpeg' instead of 'ffprobe '

```
ffmpeg -i C:\FFMpeg\bunny.mp4
```

Comment: This does not work, error saying atleast one output path should be specified

Comment: please paste the output here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a temporary text file, you could use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to execute the command (including `| findstr duration` if you want), and read from the returned file pointer the same way as you read from the file, e. g.

```
$handle = popen($command, 'r');
$line = fgets($handle);
pclose($handle);
```