# Getting the exact time duration of video in PHP

Tags: php, time, duration

I'm trying to get the exact time duration of a video in PHP. I have searched about it, but it seems to be like, I have to use the library called `getid3`, but I don't want to use it. Then I searched some code, until I found this code, but, it is wrong because, if I have 00:03:43 (hr:min:sec), the result is different. Here's my code:

```
    if (file_exists($file)){
        ## open and read video file
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        ## read video file size
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
        fclose($handle);
        $make_hexa = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-3)));
        if (strlen($contents) > $make_hexa){
            $pre_duration = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($contents,strlen($contents)-$make_hexa,3))) ;
            $post_duration = $pre_duration/1000;
            $timehours = $post_duration/3600;
            $timeminutes = ($post_duration % 3600)/60;
            $timeseconds = (($post_duration % 3600) % 60) + 1;
            $timehours = explode(".", $timehours);
            $timeminutes = explode(".", $timeminutes);
            $timeseconds = explode(".", $timeseconds);
            $duration = $timehours[0]. ":" . $timeminutes[0] . ":" . $timeseconds[0];
        }
        return $duration;
    }
    else {
        return 'File doesn\'t exists.';
    }
```

Note: I'm using Laravel5.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847873/3568847