# How to get duration, size and dimensions of video file input in Yii2?

Tags: php, html, video, yii2

I have a form that takes video file as an input. It looks like this.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

I want to get the duration, dimensions and size of the video. There is no mention about video parsing in the yiiframework documents. Is there a way to do this?

*Edit : As suggested there is getID3() for native php to work with. Is there a way to do it in Yii2 without third party libraries? If not, how do I integrate getID3() into Yii2?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)

Comment: @Ayer I'm not working with core PHP sir. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can still install this extension `getID3 ` in your Yii 2, Then use it

Comment: after upload or before upload. ??

Comment: @DharmendraSingh either one will do. Before upload would be much better though. But for my purpose either will do.

Comment: what is the formate of video..?

Comment: @DharmendraSingh .mp4, .webm and .flv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Step 1: ([Install FFmpeg from here](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg))

Step 2: To get duration of video

```
public static function getDuration($filePath)
{
    exec('ffmpeg -i'." '$filePath' 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,",$O,$S);
    if(!empty($O[0]))
    {
        return $O[0];
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Step 3: To get dimensions of video

```
 public static function getAVWidthHeight( $filePath )
{
    exec("ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 '$filePath'",$O,$S);
    if(!empty($O))
    {
        $list = [
                "width"=>explode("=",$O[0])[1],
                "height"=>explode("=",$O[1])[1],
        ];

        return $list;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `"james-heinrich/getid3": "*"` to `require` section in `project-directory/composer.json` file, then in project directory (if you have well installed composer) run command:

```
composer update
```

Then in project use it like:

```
$getID3 = new \getID3;

$file = $getID3->analyze($pathToFIle);
```

Full library will be available in your project without unnecessary imports/requires.

Answer (score -1):

Yii2 implementation of getID3()

step1 : You need to download the class file from the below url

> https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/archive/master.zip

step2 : extract it in to your vendor directory url look like this

> vendor/getID3-master/getid3/getid3.php

step3: put below code to test the result

```
public function actionIndex() { //where you need this code

  $path = \Yii::getAlias("@vendor/getID3-master/getid3/getid3.php");
  require_once($path);
  $getID3 = new \getID3;
  $file = $getID3->analyze($path_of_the_video_file);

  echo("Duration: " . $file['playtime_string'] .
    " / Dimensions: " . $file['video']['resolution_x'] . " wide by " . $file['video']['resolution_y'] . " tall" .
    " / Filesize: " . $file['filesize'] . " bytes<br />"); 

 die;// for see instant result;

}
```

Comment: You have composer to do such things like importing libraries. Don't put anything in `/vendor` path manually.

Comment: @Yupik u can give better solution. so please exaplain it..??

Comment: Is something incomprehensible in this comment?

Comment: Nothing ..just if i have to use this plug-in how can i use it in your way..??

Comment: Answered. Check and please again, don't put anything in `/vendor` manually. It's not designed for such things.