# PHP - get video and image dimensions on upload

Tags: php, html, video, upload

Is it possible to get the video dimensions from a video file? I'm uploading mp4s and wmvs as well as some image files. I would like to grab the dimensions and make it part of the new filename.

I know you can use `getImageSize()` for pictures but how would I do the same for video. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php . I'd avoid the accepted answer as it's really old, there are some newer ones in there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php require_once('getid3/getid3.php');
$filename='uploads/4thofJuly_184.mp4';
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo("Duration: ".$file['playtime_string'].
" / Dimensions: ".$file['video']['resolution_x']." wide by ".$file['video']['resolution_y']." tall".
" / Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");
$getID3 = new getID3;
$filename='uploads/25PercentOff_710.wmv';
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo("Duration: ".$file['playtime_string'].
" / Dimensions: ".$file['video']['resolution_x']." wide by ".$file['video']['resolution_y']." tall".
" / Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");

// Calling getimagesize() function 
$filename="uploads/25PercentOff_960.jpg";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename); 

// Displaying dimensions of the image 
echo "Width of image : " . $width . "<br>"; 

echo "Height of image : " . $height . "<br>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use ID3 libs, for example [getID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3):

very simple to use :

```
    $getID3 = new getID3;
    $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($localtempfilename);
```

if dont use shared host, use ffmpeg to get info ([PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)):

```
$ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$video_dimensions = $ffprobe
    ->streams( $full_video_path )   // extracts streams informations
    ->videos()                      // filters video streams
    ->first()                       // returns the first video stream
    ->getDimensions();              // returns a FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension object
```

**feature of ffmpeg:**

1. resize
2. List item
3. convert
4. frame pic (screenshot)
5. watermark
6. ...

Comment: Ive seen this however dont you have to upload it to a loction first and than move it?

Comment: uploaded files save in to temp folder .... get file info when it's in temp folder ... then move it....

Comment: is there a way to wrap it in a function that returns file width and height for both images and videos?

Comment: yes , first check file mimetype if video/xxxx run ffpmeg or other ID3 and if mimetype is image/xxxx use getImageSize

Comment: @codernoob8 note: id3 can get image, video and audio info